# Writing Apache Storm Spouts and Bolts using Python and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apache-storm

I want to turn an existing python-based implementation (a data analysis tool on a stream of events) into a storm topology.

During the research phase my team and I used python pandas a lot to develop a prototype of our tool and found it to be very helpful in terms of programmer productivity. Now we want to create a storm topology that does the same thing and aim to reuse our existing python modules as bolts or at least make an informed decision about whether it is a good idea performance-wise to do so.

Any restrictions on using a python script depending on external libs as a Storm Bolt on a cluster? Also, does anybody have a feeling for what the performance  penalty will be for using an interpreted and non-JVM language like Python instead of Java for our bolts? The pandas library itself is designed with high-performance in mind.

Thanks

Comment: Sotrm bolts will be the same python scripts with the only difference is that you will need to assume that messages (tuples) somehow magically appear in `process()` function. And yes you can use `pandas`.

Comment: Since this question is closed, I can't give you better answer on performance and experience that I had